# Uploading Document (files) to Attachment object

Tags: data-loader, attachment, upload, document

If I want to upload files into attachment object in SFDC, I can give the file path (drive location where file is available) in File location column and then upload to SFDC Attachment object.

If my files (to be attached) are already present as 'documents' within SFDC (in document object), how can i take these files and upload to attachments?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Standard Data Export Wizard and include all documents and attachments to generate the export.

Once you have the files as Zip in your local folder ,unzip and provide the path of the document in your local drive .

Alternative use services like dataloader.io to export the documents to the local machine and then upload the data .